# PHP - Verifying emails existance

Tags: php, email

So I have a code that is supposed to see if an email account exists.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
function verifyEmail($email) {
    mail($email, 'Do you exist', 'msg', 'From: from');
} 
?>
```

Although this works I want to see if an email exists without sending an email to that account. Tell me if there is an option without sending an email. I have googled this but found nothing. Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Thanks, but I am afraid all of the answers there use sending emails (except the ones that do not work)

Comment: use https://github.com/webdigi/SMTP-Based-Email-Validation.. its awesome

Comment: Thanks I will test that out tomorrow.